# alternative to base keyword in static method of derived class to call overrided method of base class

Tags: c#, radix

i have following code

```
    class A{
            public void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class A");
            }
    }
    class B:A{
            public void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class B");
            }
            public static void show()
            {
                    //base.display(); gives error
            }
    }
```

in above code base.display(); gives error.I have to call the base class method display() in method show() without creating object of class A.how can i do this? or I can't do this?

Comment: Have you tried `new A().display()`?

Comment: Why not just remove the static key workd from B show()?

Comment: @simon thanx, it works using new A().display(),but is any other way to don't use new A().display and access non-static method of override method of base class in static method of derived class.the problem trigger to me in extension method of class B.

Comment: You're technically not overriding the display-method in class B, you're just declaring a new one with the same name. I bet your compiler gives you a warning indicating this.

Answer (score 5):

A `static` method does not belong to an instance, hence it has no `base`. You can only say `A.display()` if `A.display()` is also a `static` method. You can also say `new A().display()` to discard the instance after calling `display()`.

Comment: if A.display() is non-static then it work using new A().display() but if A.display is static then it is not working.But my question about any alternative for base keyword in static method

Comment: If A.display() is static then you simply call it using A.display(). There is no need for new. There is no equivalent of base in static since static stuff doesn't support inheritance. While inside a static method you must refer to the name of the parent class A directly.

Comment: if static doesn't support inheritance,so we can't call base class members in static method,so there will be no keyword alternative for base in static method,ok thanx.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use instance data in a static method.

A static method should be self-contained. This is to say that it will
perform its function without requiring or saving any stateful data.

```
 class A{
            public static void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class A");
            }
    }
      class B : A
      {
          public void display()
          {
              Console.WriteLine("In class B");
          }
          public static void show()
          {
              A.display(); 
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because you are calling an instance method from a static method which is not allowed.

You have 3 options here. You can choose whatever suits you well.

**Option 1.**

```
class A{
        public void display()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("In class A");
        }
}
class B:A{
        public void display()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("In class B");
        }
        public void show()
        {
                base.display();
        }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
class A{
            public static void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class A");
            }
    }
    class B:A{
            public void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class B");
            }
            public void show()
            {
                    A.display();
            }
    }
```

**Option 3:**

```
class A{
            public void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class A");
            }
    }
    class B:A{
            public void display()
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("In class B");
            }
            public void show()
            {
                    new A().display();
            }
    }
```